# A problem involving handshakes and probability with combinatorial elements to prove

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

[image: click to view]

My approach in this problem was to use combinatorial arguments. To admit, I cannot understand leave alone solve it. I need to start off...I am actually confused between the probability and the combinatorial part....

Comment: Ok, so I think you need to distingush two cases, (1) i,j have met and (2) i,j did not meet.. The rest seem to come from simple combinatorics and binomial distributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

There are $(n-2)$ people at the party other than $i, j \,$ where $i \ne j$.

A) If $i$ and $j$ meet each other

$i$ and $j$ need to meet $(k-1)$ and $(l-1)$ people respectively from rest $(n-2)$ people.

Number of ways of $i$ meeting $(k-1)$ of $(n-2)$ people $ = {n-2 \choose k-1}$

Similarly for $j$.

$i$ meets any other person with probability $p$ and does not meet with probability $(1-p)$. Same for $j$. Please also consider that $i$ and $j$ meet each other with probability $p$.

Probability that both events occur ($i$ meeting $k$ people and $j$ meeting $l$ people) will be multiplication of both probabilities.

B) If $i$ and $j$ do not meet each other.

Number of ways of $i$ meeting $k$ of $(n-2)$ people $ = {n-2 \choose k}$. Similarly for $j$.

You go on to calculate the probability similar to case $A$.

Comment: Can you tell where the $p^{k+l-1}$ comes from

Comment: $i$ meeting $(k-1)$ people and $j$ meeting $(l-1)$ people. That is $(k+l-2)$. Plus they meet each other with probability $p$ so $(k+l-1)$.